# Error when reading similar text files in java

Tags: java, linux, string

Im reading 2  files one at a time but one of them is not being read properly. Text files are from Linux,

```
/sbin/ifconfig | grep "inet addr:" > ips.txt
```

lines look like this:

```
  inet addr:77.221.133.178  Bcast:77.221.133.183  Mask:255.255.255.248
  inet addr:77.221.133.179  Bcast:77.221.133.183  Mask:255.255.255.248
  inet addr:77.221.133.180  Bcast:77.221.133.183  Mask:255.255.255.248
```

lines from file that can't be read:

```
  inet addr:192.64.177.185  Bcast:192.64.177.255  Mask:255.255.255.128
      inet addr:192.64.182.2  Bcast:192.64.182.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
      inet addr:192.64.182.3  Bcast:192.64.182.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
```

the java program needs to extract only the IPs. File 1 is being read properly but from File 2 only the first IP is taken. They're from 2 different servers. One is Centos 6.3 and the other is Centos 6.6 .I guess its some formatting or encoding problem but I can't figure it out.  code that's extracting the IPs

```
static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
File file = new File("C:\path\ips.txt"); 

        Scanner scan = null;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(file);
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                extractIP(scan.nextLine());
             }

            System.out.println("IPs: "+list.size());
            System.out.println(list.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file with IPs not found");
        } finally {
            if (scan != null) {
                scan.close();
            }
        }
static void extractIP (String ipString){
    String[] strarr = ipString.split("inet addr:");
    if (!(strarr[1].contains("127"))){
    list.add(strarr[1].substring(0, strarr[1].indexOf(" ")));
    }
}
```

I avoid using regex for IP because its extracting the Broadcast IP as well.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Have you tried diffing the files? (BTW: you can use regex in this case too.)

Comment: sorry the files are not completely identical (will edit) but they're with the same structure - just different IPs for the different servers. @peterremec the error is that from the 2nd file only the 1st IP is taken. and the 1st file is read properly

Comment: In cases like this, first thing to do is open the files in a hex editor to make sure the file does not contain any control characters, or that your spaces are spaces and not tabs.

Comment: You didn't show us the read loop you are using. Are you reading them at the same time? One after another? Running your program twice?

Comment: Could you show also file 2? Maybe in the second file there is a `tab` character instead of a `space` or two spaces instead of one or ...

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ive included the reading loop. Im copying the file on my Windows PC for testing purposes. I read them 1 at a time - just change the file name in java.

Comment: OK, can you post the two files? It may well be a problem with the content.

Answer (score 0):

The second and the third line of file2 contain `127` in the `Bcast` field.

**edit** If you can run your code on the Linux machine and not limitted to read from a text file, you could get all inet addresses as

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
for (NetworkInterface iface : Collections.list(nets)) {
    List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(iface.getInetAddresses());
    for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
        System.out.println(addr.toString().split("/")[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. I edited it to !((ipString.contains("127.0.0.1")) and its working. Your suggestion maybe the better way to do this job. Thanks everyone for the quick responses.